# What does 1604 SQL syntax error importing database mean?

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to import a database to a new server.
when I try I get an error.
it says there is an issue with my syntax. I didn't write the syntax, I just exported it from the current server. this is the code the error highlights.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='en' dir='ltr' class='ie ie11'><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><style>html{display: none;
```

Does anyone know what the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the content you have posted isn't SQL. SQL is the language or file format that MySQL is expecting when you import and this line doesn't mean anything to your database server (it appears to be a portion of HTML). How did you generate the export from your old server? Something seem to have gone wrong with that process.